# PHP: Split unix timestamp range into 5 chuncks

Tags: php, pchart

I have a requirement where I need to extract 5 points from a Unix time stamp or PHP time stamp range.

For Example, 
From 2014-06-26 07:53:26 to 2014-06-27 07:52:46.

I need five points from these two dates in exact or approximate intervals, to chart using pChart.

Currently My Code is

```
$diff = $mintime->diff($maxtime);
$range = max($timestamps) - min($timestamps);
$cnt = count($timestamps);
$temp = ceil($range * (20/100));

for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
{
if($i%($cnt/5) == 0)
$point[$i] = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",min($timestamps) + $temp * ($i+1));
else
$point[$i] = null;
}
```

But My Code returns erratic values. I know the problem is with the temp variable. Help me solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$from = '2014-06-26 07:53:26';
$to = '2014-06-27 07:52:46';

$diff_stamp = strtotime($to) - strtotime($from);
$range = range(strtotime($from), strtotime($to), $diff_stamp/4);
```

Here, `$range` is an array of timestamps. To convert each back to a date, you could use `array_map`:

```
$range = array_map(function($a){return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a);}, $range);
```

[**See Demo** *Updated*](http://3v4l.org/b8lKW)

---

*Resources:*
[strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), [range()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php), [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$splitter=($timestamp1-$timestamp2);
$timestamp_between=array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) $timestamp_between[]=$timestamp1+($i*$splitter);
print_r($timestamp_between);
```